# Waiting on input from Socket in Xamarin Froms

Tags: xamarin, service

## GOAL

The application needs to constantly read from a socket - and when it receives a line that is not empty it needs to do an appropriate action.

## Issue

From what I researched you can't do services in Xamarin Forms, since each service is platform dependent. (IOS, Andoird, Windows). So what I am looking for as a way to constantly monitor inputs from a Bluetooth port in this case, simply by calling a already defined function.

## Tried

I tried using a Refresh view. But there were issues with that from a code point of view and a visual point of view.

## Current Code

This is what I have tried, but unfortuntately it has mixed results. The socket seems to connect when first pairing but then closed if I try to read:

```
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(miliseconds), () =>
        {
            command.Execute(null);
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: You can use  MVVM with `INotifyPropertyChanged` in Xamarin.Forms, You can read the data from a socket in background service constantly.  If the value of perperties of model changed, the view will be changed at the same time.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Code to show what are you trying? There are few Bluetooth plugins, you can subscribe to event and get the data.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I don't have an issue with data bindings, the issue I am struggling with is with the `read the data from a socket in background service constantly` part. That I do not know how to do --- constantly.

@Preteek  I end up using the following code - it works, but not 100%, I've updated my question

Comment: In the Android Part, you can open a foreground service to read the data:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT most it as an answer

Comment: If you want to know the IOS and Windows part, you can open another threads. I am farmilar with IOS and Windows.